# How to compare the string stored in two list in python?

Tags: python, list

Issue is with the loop

I can't iterate and check the value from `solu` with `dgu` list.

It prints above output `upto` `print(solu)`

The loop used later lags and stops there with no output and I'm clueless here.

Could Someone explain how to compare strings if they exist in two different files from different sources?

```
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
import deepdiff
from pprint import pprint
import xlrd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import xlsxwriter
import tocamelcase
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
import numpy as np

xlsx = ExcelFile('WrongSpelling.xlsx')
df = xlsx.parse(xlsx.sheet_names[0])

dg = pd.read_csv("pfm.csv", usecols = ['Place Id','Name','Category'])
pla = dg['Place Id'].values.tolist()
nam = dg['Name'].values.tolist()
cat = dg['Category'].values.tolist()

print()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Spelling'])
bat= df2['Spelling'].values.tolist()

namo = [x.lower() for x in nam]
bato = [x.lower() for x in bat]

sol = set(namo) & set(bato)
solu = list(sol)
dgu= dg.values.tolist()
nam=list(nam)

print(solu)

print()

print("The Count of Matches with the incorrect data is" ,len(solu))

print(dg[:5])


print()

while i < len(dgu):
    while i < len(solu):
        # a = solu[i]
        # b = dgu[i]
        # c = nam[i]
        if solu[i] in dgu[i]:
            print(dgu[i])
        else:
            pass
    i+=1
```

Comment: I wonder how this even executes, as `i` in your while-loop is not set to a value. When checking `i < len(dgu)` I suppose the code crashes. You should definitively switch to a for-loop in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner while loop is using the variable `i` as the conditional to when it passes the length of `solu`, but you enver increment within that while loop, so it will loop forever checking for `i < len(solu)` which will never evaluate to `False` if it enters the loop the first time.

As @offeltoffel mentioned, for loop seems to fit your need better here. Without being able to compile your code without a verifiable example, here is what the for loop could look like:

```
for i in range(len(dgu):
    for j in range(len(solu)):
        if solu[j] in dgu[i]:
            print(dgu[i])
        # don't need elsepass here, as it serves no purpose
    # don't need to increment i/j in a for loop manually as it iterates through the range created from the length of dgu/solu
```

Comment: Just a different question on the same lines and codes-     code - 
ball = pd.DataFrame(bl, columns=['Place ID','Name','Category'])

for i in range(len(dgu)):
    for j in range(len(solu)):
        a = solu[j]
        b = dgu[i]
        if a in b:
            bl=dgu[i]
            print(bl)
            # DataFrame(df, columns = ['Spelling'])
            ball.to_csv('wordsdetector.csv', index=False, header=False)
        else:
            pass
print() # It doesn't write the output in csv and I'm unsure what broke it!